# RSS to JSON converter doesn't always seem to work

Tags: php, json, rss

I'm converting a medium RSS feed into JSON so I can display it on my website:

```
$data = "https://medium.com/@idrawcharts";
$whatIWant = substr($data, strpos($data, "@") + 1);
$rss_url = 'https://medium.com/feed/@' . $whatIWant;
$api_endpoint = 'https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=';
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents($api_endpoint . urlencode($rss_url)) , true );

<?php if ($data) { ?>

    <?php foreach ($data['items'] as $item) { ?>

        <?php

        $mediumPostTitle = $item['title'];
        $mediumPostTitle = mb_strimwidth($mediumPostTitle, 0, 60);
        $mediumPostTitle = mb_strimwidth($mediumPostTitle, 0, 57, '...');

        ?>

    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

If I hit the full endpoint here - https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@idrawcharts

the feed works just fine.

But for some reason the line with $data = json_encode... does not output anything.

Is there something in my code causing this to not work every time or is it an issue with the API?

Thanks!

Comment: [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)  maybe this will tell you something?  JSON is very sensitive to non UTF8 encodings.  You can try something like this to clean it if that is the case `$string = preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]]/', '',$string);`

Comment: I also faced the same problem. I thought if you update some posts then It won't work for a while.